# Will the 'finally' block be called with an early return in a 'try' block?

Tags: javascript

I am running automated tests in a Docker container and using a browser in this environment. I have a concern about whether the browser is closing properly in the scenario below. My code includes a try block with an early return statement. My question is: In JavaScript, if I execute an early return in a try block, will the finally block still be triggered? I want to ensure that the browser is closed correctly in my Docker-based test environment.

```js
try {
  await importWallet(params.seedPhrase, page, extensionId)
  await addNetwork({networkName: 'BTC', page, extensionId})
  await connectWallet(context, page)
  return await sendToken({page, params})
}
finally {
  await context.close()
  console.log(' Closing browser')
}
```

I ran my test, but I am unable to verify it as it runs in a Docker container.

Comment: perhaps there’s somewhere else you can run JavaScript where you could verify how `finally` works

Comment: Why return from try at all? If you want to close the browser after sendToken, then leave the `return` out and it will do that. If you want it to only run in the case of an exception, then close the browser in a catch.

Comment: You should try the function and catch that instead.

Answer (score 1):

`finally` block is executed right before returning from `try`. If you return from `finally` the returned value from `try` is ignored despite being evaluated.

From MDN, when `finally` is executed (one of the options):

> Immediately before a control-flow statement (return, throw, break,
> continue) is executed in the try block or catch block.

```js
const logTry = () => new Promise(r => setTimeout(() => r(console.log('try') ?? true), 500));

async function test(){
  try{
    return await logTry();
  }finally{
    console.log('finally');
    return await false;
  }
}

test().then(console.log);
```

The same for throwing an error:

```js
const logTry = () => new Promise(r => setTimeout(() => r(console.log('try') ?? true), 500));

async function test(){
  try{
    return await logTry(); 
  }finally{
    console.log('finally');
    throw new Error('finally errored');
  }
}

test().catch(e => console.log(e.message));
```

Answer (score 0):

The try statement defines a code block to run (to try).

The catch statement defines a code block to handle any error.

The finally statement defines a code block to run regardless of the result.

The throw statement defines a custom error.

So for your question, Finally statement will work for sure when you run error handling.

Answer (score 0):

> I ran my test, but I am unable to verify it as it runs in a Docker container.

If only there was a convenient JavaScript runtime available in some ubiquitous application like your browser...

```js
/* Mocks */
const delayLog = (...args) => new Promise((r) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(...args);
    r('token');
  }, 10);
});
const importWallet = delayLog.bind(null, 'importWallet');
const addNetwork = delayLog.bind(null, 'addNetwork');
const connectWallet = delayLog.bind(null, 'connectWallet');
const sendToken = delayLog.bind(null, 'sendToken');
const context = { close: delayLog.bind(null, 'context.close') };

/* Test */
const asyncTest = async (params, page, extensionId) => {
  try {
    await importWallet(params.seedPhrase, page, extensionId)
    await addNetwork({networkName: 'BTC', page, extensionId})
    await connectWallet(context, page)
    return await sendToken({page, params})
  }
  finally {
    await context.close()
    console.log(' Closing browser')
  }
}

asyncTest({ seedPhrase: 'acorn' }, 1, '.js').then(console.info);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

You can clearly see from the logged output that the async code in the `finally` is evaluated and awaited before resolving the promise with the `return` value.